# Error al agregar un separador a un menú

Tags: c#

No he usado un separador y no se como utilizarlo, tengo este código con un menú y quiero utilizar un separador en el, pero me da error y no especifica cual:

```
BarraDeMenus = new MenuStrip();
this.BarraDeMenus.Name = "BarraDeMenus";
this.BarraDeMenus.Size = new Size(492, 24);
this.BarraDeMenus.TabIndex = 3;
this.BarraDeMenus.Text = "Barra de menus";
this.MainMenuStrip = this.BarraDeMenus;
this.Controls.Add(BarraDeMenus);

menuArchivo = new ToolStripMenuItem();
menuArchivo.Name = "menuArchivo";
menuArchivo.Text = "&Archivo";
BarraDeMenus.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { menuArchivo });


ArchivoNuevo = new ToolStripMenuItem();
ArchivoNuevo.Name = "ArchivoNuevo";
ArchivoNuevo.Text = "&Nuevo";
ArchivoNuevo.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.N;
ArchivoNuevo.ShowShortcutKeys = true;
menuArchivo.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { ArchivoNuevo });

ArchivoAbrir = new ToolStripMenuItem();
ArchivoAbrir.Name = "ArchivoAbrir";
ArchivoAbrir.Text = "&Abrir";
ArchivoAbrir.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.A;
ArchivoAbrir.ShowShortcutKeys = true;
menuArchivo.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { ArchivoAbrir });

ArchivoGuardar = new ToolStripMenuItem();
ArchivoGuardar.Name = "ArchivoGuardar";
ArchivoGuardar.Text = "&Guardar";
ArchivoGuardar.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.G;
ArchivoGuardar.ShowShortcutKeys = true;
menuArchivo.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { ArchivoGuardar });

ArchivoGuardarComo = new ToolStripMenuItem();
ArchivoGuardarComo.Name = "ArchivoAbrir";
ArchivoGuardarComo.Text = "&Guardar Como";
menuArchivo.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { ArchivoGuardarComo });

Separador=new ToolStripSeparator();
Separador.Name="Separador";
menuArchivo.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[]{ArchivoNuevo,ArchivoAbrir,ArchivoGuardar,ArchivoGuardarComo,Separador,ArchivoSalir});//Aqui me da el error

ArchivoSalir = new ToolStripMenuItem();
ArchivoSalir.Name = "ArchivoSalir";
ArchivoSalir.Text = "&Salir";
menuArchivo.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[]{ ArchivoSalir });
```

Answer (score 0):

Claro que te da error:

```
Separador=new ToolStripSeparator();
Separador.Name="Separador";
menuArchivo.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[]{ArchivoNuevo,ArchivoAbrir,ArchivoGuardar,ArchivoGuardarComo,Separador,ArchivoSalir});

ArchivoSalir = new ToolStripMenuItem();
ArchivoSalir.Name = "ArchivoSalir";
ArchivoSalir.Text = "&Salir";
```

En la línea que tienes el error estás intentando añadir `ArchivoSalir` antes de definirlo. Simplemente,quita `ArchivoSalir` de la linea que te da el error.